# PHP Json only a first result

Tags: php, json

My issue is that when I use `foreach` trough my JSON commands it will only give the first command. In this case HELP but not the second one that is Test.

How can I fix this?

PHP:

```
echo "Commands:<br>";
$json = file_get_contents("App/cmd/commands.json");
$register = json_decode($json, true);
$command = $_GET["c"];
foreach ($register['commands'] as $key => $value){
    echo $key;
    if($command == $key)
    {
        echo "Found!";
        return;
    }
    if(isset($register["commands"][$key]["alias"])){
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp; Has Aliases<Br>";
        $aliases = explode(",", $register["commands"][$key]["alias"]);
        foreach ($aliases as $alias)
        {
            if($command == $alias)
            {
                echo "Found!";
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    echo "Not Found!";
    return;
}
```

My Json:

```
{"help":"value","commands":{"help":{"function":"test"},"test":{"function":"test"}}}
```

Comment: "alias" is not in your sample data

Comment: What are you passing in `$_GET["c"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have `return;` everywhere. Then you can't have a second iteration, because you always finish the process. Remove the return according to your logic to have a second iteration and make proper refactor to your code, to make it functional.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will make the change!

Answer (score 3):

It is because you set

```
   echo "Not Found!"; return;
```

in the loop so there is no chance for second iteration. That code should be after loop not inside.